# How to prevent timeout in Dataflow in Azure Data Factory when ingesting data into Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, azure-data-factory

My source is a directory in Azure data lake with roughly 70,000 JSON files.
Each file has certain properties and one of them is an array of complex `Node` elements.
In total, the JSON files have around 13 million of such `Node` elements.

Using Azure Data Factory and a DataFlow I want to flatten the arrays in each JSON file and insert them as rows into a Kusto DB.

On a "General purpose" integration unit I'm getting an out of memory error. On a memory optimized instance the job runs for about 40 minutes and then fails with the message below.

What I tried:

- Increase the timeout in the Kusto sink. It's set to 36,000 seconds (10 hours).
- Increase the compute size to 8+8 memory optimized.
- The Kusto cluster is configured to a min instance count of 2 with a max of 4 but I cannot see any scale out events.

What are my options to optimize the ingestion?
If other information is required, please let me know in the comments.

> Operation on target ExportNodesToKusto failed:
> {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to
> reason: at Sink 'KustoNodesSink': Timed out trying to ingest
> requestId:
> 'a23025d4-f1e7-48cd-a5f9-a4d8dbaec64e'","Details":"shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.kusto.spark.exceptions.TimeoutAwaitingPendingOperationException:
> Timed out trying to ingest requestId:
> 'a23025d4-f1e7-48cd-a5f9-a4d8dbaec64e'\n\tat
> shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasink.KustoWriter$$anonfun$ingestRowsIntoKusto$1.apply(KustoWriter.scala:201)\n\tat
> shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasink.KustoWriter$$anonfun$ingestRowsIntoKusto$1.apply(KustoWriter.scala:198)\n\tat
> scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)\n\tat
> scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)\n\tat
> scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)\n\tat
> scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)\n\tat
> shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasink.KustoWriter$.ingestRowsIntoKusto(KustoWriter.scala:198)\n\tat
> shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasink.KustoWriter$.ingestToTemporaryTableByWorkers(KustoWriter.scala:247)\n\tat
> shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasink.KustoWriter$.ingestRowsIntoTem"}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its getting bottlenecked at the sink, so resources on Kusto side is not enough. Try further adding resources on Kusto side. If it doesnt work, try creating a support ticket because those runIDs need to be looked at deeper, potentially requiring further help from Data Explorer team.